# Dangers of using reflection to add files to classpath at runtime

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

Recently I have been looking for ways to dynamically load jar files into my application at runtime.

I have come along a certain solution several times, which is basically a "hack" that gets the system classloader and uses reflection to access the otherwisep rotected addURL method in order to add additional files to the original classpath at runtime. This solution supposendly works really well and avoids the problems that occur when writing and using a selfmade custom class loader.

It looks something like this:

```
URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;

try {
      Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", parameters);
      method.setAccessible(true);
      method.invoke(sysloader, new Object[] { u });
 } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
      throw new IOException("Error, could not add URL to system classloader");
 }
```

My question is as follows: I assume there is a really good reason for making the addURL method protected in the first place, there must be some kind of pitfalls or dangers when adding files to the classpath dynamically.

Besides assuming the system classloader is always a URLClassLoader, which "should always be the case" (TM), what kind of trouble could I run into when using this "hack"?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to change the *system* classloader instead of creating a new classloader instance which knows about the extra jar files?

Comment: i am not entirely sure to be honest. i'm very new to the concept of classloaders in general, so there is still a lot about them that i don't fully understand.
i read somewhere else here on stackoverflow that using a custom classloader can cause problems in certain situations, for example if i use it to load a library that has already been loaded via the default classpath at programm startup.

this "hack" above, even though it's pretty nasty, was deemed to be the only method of loading jars at runtime without risk of running into dependency/incompatibility problems.

Comment: Well are you *trying* to load libraries which are already in the default classpath? This hack sounds much riskier than using the *designed* approach of separate classloaders.

Comment: i am trying to load plugins that make use of (some of) the same libraries as my main programm. the way i understand it is this: if i use this hack, a lib that was already on the classpath at programm startup wouldn't be loaded once again during runtime (because the classloader is interelligent enough to not do that), hence there would be no problems. if i use a custom classloader however, the library would be loaded twice (once using the system classloader at startup, once using my custom classloader during runtime) which could lead to problems down the road.

Comment: I would *strongly* advise you to isolate things. Potentially load your main program in one classloader, and each plugin in a separate one. That way any misuses of the libraries in one plugin can't affect the others, or your programs. That is *designed* to work. However, you seem determined to go ahead with the unsupported way, and I doubt that I'll be able to convince you otherwise. Good luck...

Comment: Thanks so far for your input! if i use a seperate classloader for each plugin, how would i ensure the "isolation"? Also, which problems would i face when i want these plugins to communicate with the main programm or with each other? It's just that the "hack" solution seems pretty straightforward, while the solution using seperate classloaders seems to be significantly more complex and like it bears more potential for dependency/incompatibility problems. Really appreciate your input so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary danger is your relying on a run time check of the methods existence.

If the method signature changes in the future, you won't know about it till run time.  This could also leave in a nasty situation if no alternative method is provided.

Also, as huge already states, the designers choose to make the method `protected` for a reason (other then lack of forethought)